# Good maintainable solution for Windows AppData on second harddrive

Tags: windows, symbolic-link

Say you have a small SSD and a second HDD.

You install programs on the HDD, but because your Windows is installed on the SSD, it still wants to put the program's AppData/Local files on your SSD instead.

So you think "I will symlink the SSD's AppData folder to the HDD's AppData folder!" But now, when you actually want to install some programs on the SSD, the AppData for that program will be on the HDD.

Instead, you can symlink each individual folder for a program on the SSD's AppData/Local folder, but what a pain in the butt!

Does anyone use a neater solution for the best of both worlds? 
The obvious design solution is to have a folder for all SSD AppData stuff, and another folder that's symlinked to all programs installed on HDD.

But the issue is maintenance! You'd have to do it manually every time. The real challenge and puzzle is to have this maintained without manually touching things every time you install or uninstall a program, which means leveraging existing Windows install behavior of AppData folder designation.

(If only Windows was smart enough to automatically place AppData files in the appropriate harddrive!)

Comment: Manually set install locations?

Comment: That sounds ideal. How would you do that?